# Navigation Hover CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover

I am trying to create a `nav` bar. I added a logo in the top left of the `nav` bar and links "Home", "Contacts", and "Products" in the top right.

I am trying to put `:hover` on the logo link with `padding: 9px 12px` and I get a problem with it.

When the cursor is over the logo, then the hover moves the whole navigation bar about 3px.

I tried to make the `nav` bar and links bigger, but then it does not look good.

Here is my code:

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(144, 144, 144);
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.nav__logo {
    background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
    padding: 7px 9px;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.nav__logo a {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
}

.nav__logo:hover {
    background-color: rgb(176, 176, 176);
    padding: 9px 12px;
}

.nav__logo-text {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 23px;
}

.nav__single-link {
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.nav__single-link:hover {
    background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <div class="nav__logo">
            <a class="nav__logo-text" href="./index.html">CampHouse</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav__links">
            <a class="nav__single-link" href="./index.html">Home</a>
            <a class="nav__single-link" href="./products.html">Products</a>
            <a class="nav__single-link" href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you still want it to "grow"? Because if not you can simply remove `padding: 9px 12px;` from `.nav__logo:hover`

Comment: You can try to set fixed height of nav element for example height: 70px;

Answer (score 0):

the increased padding is pushing the whole nav down because padding, margins and borders take up space.
Anyways, I think I know what you're trying to do, instead write this:

```
.nav__logo:hover {
background-color: rgb(176, 176, 176);
transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

This way, when you hover the element, it will increase its visual size by 10 percent on each axis, for more info you can look [at Mozilla's scale() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me. I think I found a solution by myself, but don't know is that correct to use it. I've replaced :hover on ".nav__logo a" instead of ".nav__logo". And it worked for me. Correct me if I'm wrong :/

Comment: It's alright, many paths lead to Rome and at the end of the day, most of these things rely on personal taste more than anything! I like to use transform & scale, but if you got it to work using other methods and feel comfortable working that way, go ahead!
Note that there are some things that do matter but you can look them up as "Best practices" + whichever topic you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your general styling and give it `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform: scale` instead of `padding` on `:hover`. In your example, the `height` is determined by `padding` on either `nav` or its containing elements, such as `nav__logo`. When you increase the padding on the containing elements, the `height` on the `nav` will also grow.

This can be resolved by adding a `max-height` on `nav` if you wanted to go the `padding` route. You can also set the `:hover` directly on the `a` instead of the `div`. However, `transform: scale` seems more fitting here.

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(144, 144, 144);
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.nav__logo {
    background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
    padding: 7px 9px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.nav__logo a {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
}

.nav__logo:hover {
    background-color: rgb(176, 176, 176);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.nav__logo-text {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 23px;
}

.nav__single-link {
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.nav__single-link:hover {
    background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <div class="nav__logo">
            <a class="nav__logo-text" href="./index.html">CampHouse</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav__links">
            <a class="nav__single-link" href="./index.html">Home</a>
            <a class="nav__single-link" href="./products.html">Products</a>
            <a class="nav__single-link" href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I answered to Bruno. I've found working solution. But I've never tried "transform", so I need to read some about it and try to use it as you said. Maybe it will works much better then my founded solution. :) Thanks

Comment: @Paulius "You can also set the `:hover` directly on the `a` instead of the `div`." This quote from my solution looks like that's what you did based on your comment to Bruno.

Comment: Oh.. Okay than, but also I should learn about transfrom for the future solutions :D

Comment: @Paulius It's simple. `transform` simply makes elements larger or smaller on the `y` or `x-axis`. If no axis is specified e.g., `transform: scale()` then it will be on both axis. So you were trying to make your element larger by giving it more padding, it can be accomplished just the same with transform. `transform: scale(1.1)` is simply instructing the browser to make it 1.1 * its current size.

Answer (score 0):

Try the hover on `.nav__logo a:hover` instead of `.nav__logo:hover`

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(144, 144, 144);
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.nav__logo a {
  background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
  padding: 7px 9px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
}

.nav__logo a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(176, 176, 176);
  padding: 9px 12px;
}

.nav__logo-text {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.nav__single-link {
  padding: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.nav__single-link:hover {
  background-color: rgb(208, 208, 208);
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="nav__logo">
      <a class="nav__logo-text" href="./index.html">CampHouse</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav__links">
      <a class="nav__single-link" href="./index.html">Home</a>
      <a class="nav__single-link" href="./products.html">Products</a>
      <a class="nav__single-link" href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```